# Using "shift" function in R to subtract one row from another by group

Tags: r

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
dt
   id month balance
1:  1     4     100
2:  1     5      50
3:  2     4     200
4:  2     5     135
5:  3     4     100
6:  3     5     100
7:  4     5     300
```

"id" is the client's ID, "month" indicates what month it is, and "balance" indicates the account balance of a client. In a sense, this is longitudinal data where, say, element (2,3) indicates that Client #1 has an account balance of 50 at the end of month 5.

I want to generate a column that will give me the difference between a client's balance between month 5 and 4 to know the transactions carried out from one month to another.

This new variable should let me know that Client 1 drew 50, Client 2 drew 65 and Client 3 didn't do anything in aggregate terms between april and may. Client 4 is a new client that joined in may.

I thought of the following code:

```
dt$transactions <- dt$balance - shift(dt$balance, 1, "up")
```

However, it does not work properly because it's telling me that Client 4 made a 200 dollar deposit (but Client 4 is new!). Therefore, I want to be able to introduce the argument "by=id" to this somehow.

I know the solution lies in using the following notation:

```
dt[, transactions := balance - shift(balance, ??? ), by=id]
```

I just need to figure out how to make the aforementioned code work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this not work? `df[, transactions := balance - shift(balance, 1), by = id]`

Comment: df[, transaction :=  diff(balance) , by = id].. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That actually works. I found this to be a better solution though: 

    _dt[, transaction := balance - first(balance), by = id]_. Tank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I only have two observations (at most), the following code gives me an elegant solution:

```
dt[, transaction := balance - first(balance), by = id]
```

This prevents any NAs from entering the variable *transaction*.

However, if I had more observations per id, I would do the following:

```
dt[,transaction := balance - shift(balance,1), by = id]
```

Big thanks to @Ryan and @Onyambu for helping.